# Urls aren't being erased in field

Tags: html, url

I'm building a website and on some of the pages I've created if I click a link it'll add it to the url instead of it being its own.
I have already checked closing brackets and such, not sure if this is some sort of PHP or DB error I haven't heard of.

For example, on `www.homepage.com/about` I click contacts link it shows up:
 `www.homepage.com/aboutwww.homepage.com/contacts`

This is how I have links in html for the most part:
`<li><a href="www.homepage.com/about/">About</a></li>`

Any ideas would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Can we see some code or we need to guess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to specify the hostname in a URL, then you must use either an absolute URL (e.g. starting with `https://` or `http://`) or a scheme-relative URL (starting with `//`).

Since you aren't doing that, the URL is being resolved relative to that of the current document.